# Do US politicians consider the 2008 Global Financial Crisis Finished?

Tags: united-states, economy, financial-crisis

Do *politicians*, in the US, consider "2008 Global Financial Crisis" Finished? or  not?
What signs for each side they mention?

Comment: How is this opinion based? It's not asking if we think the financial crisis is over, it's asking whether a specific group of politicians treat it as over in their speeches and writings.

Comment: I don't think it is at all clear what "Finished" means in this context, or what "signs" means. Unless that's clarified, I think this question needs to be closed as unclear.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think they really understand what happened. Analysts today are still trying to understand what exactly happened, for example just this year a book called Crashed by Adam Tooze was released. The book is an attempt to dissect and figure out what exactly happened to this crisis that is already ten years old.